# how to (line) break output at specific keyword?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Situation: PHP-based CMS (OpenCart 2.0.3.1) -> category page -> outputs the product names via:
`<?php echo $product['name']; ?>`

Problem: need to wrap *a portion* of the product name, to the next line. For example, what currently displays as `20-inch Blue Widget For Golfers` should display as

```
20-inch Blue
Widget for Golfers
```

So every product that has the word "Widget" (or "AnotherKeyword" in it), should have a `<br>` before it.

How can this be done?

P.S. Changing the product name itself to include a `<br>` or `&lt;br&gt;` doesn't work, since OpenCart displays whatever is in the Product Name field literally, ignoring HTML. (Unless someone can point me in the direction of "how to echo the $product[name] but actually process the HTML in it").

Comment: Replace `widget` with `<br />widget`?

Comment: @u_mulder He says that won't work, because it displays the element literally, not as HTML.

Comment: It sounds like it actually outputs it as `echo htmlentities($product['name'])`. Unless there's a way for you to wrap the whole thing in an element like `<pre>`, I'm not sure there's any way for you to add line breaks to it.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose template can be modified somehow. Otherwise - what OP can change without accessing a template?

Comment: I can change the template, I have full access to all the core files. I just don't know how to implement this particular change.

Comment: The entire line that controls the output of the product name is:

`<h4 class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>`

...unless I can somehow change the `echo $product['name']` to process the HTML tags? That would solve my problem, as a work-around. (I would still have to insert the "<br>" into every product name, but it's doable).

I would prefer to have a solution that doesn't involve adding extra junk into the actual product data though...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can first replace in php "Widget" with a br in front and then via jquery wrap all this way:

```
<script>
    $(".name a").text(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<pre />');
    })
</script>
```